# MOODLE :: custom tree menu block

Tags: moodle

I am using moodle2.8. Can we create custom tree menu style using a block. or can we add custom tree style menu items using a default html block as html editor has ordered and unordered list style but we don't have a tree style.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know the moodle there is no way to do this, We can not create the custom tree menu block through html block by default.